# Swift alamofire multiform patch request

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am using Alamofire to upload a picture with some data to a rest api that I have and I have been able to get it to work with a post request but when using put/patch request no data is being sent to the server.

```
AF.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        if let name = user.name.data(using: .utf8){
            multipartFormData.append(name, withName: "name")
        }
        if let email = user.name.data(using: .utf8){
            multipartFormData.append(email, withName: "email")
        }

        if let cover = cover {
            multipartFormData.append(cover.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.6)!, withName: "cover", fileName: "image.png", mimeType: "image/jpg")
        }
    }, to: "https://test.com/api/v1/users/\(id)", method: .patch, headers: headers)
        .responseJSON { (response) in
            print(response)
    }
```

when checking the on the api end nothing is in the request when it is being sent to attempts the call. and the data is there I am able to get data to print out in swift

Comment: Did you gone with difference between Put/Patch/Post request ?. Each one has different usage.

Comment: I know the difference. I am updating a record.